# Pushing Iterated Rows Depending on Number Selected in Reactive Forms in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular4-forms

I've a problem in iterating rows when i selecting a number in my dropdown. How would i push that number so that rows(cards) would be iterated depending on that number. My process is this, first you have to select Solo Traveller as 'No' so that the adults and children dropdowns would appear. That dropdown is my problem, how would i iterate rows(cards) depending on that number selected? I've made the rows(cards) but i don't know how would i iterate it. here's my stackblitz link

[CLICK THIS LINK](https://stackblitz.com/edit/iterated-according-to-selected-number?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
 updateCountAdult(value) {
    console.log(value.target.value);
    this.form.addControl('adultRows', this.adultRows);
  }

  updateCountChildren(value) {
    console.log(value.target.value);
    this.form.addControl('childrenRows', this.childrenRows);
  }

  addAdult(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      firstName: [null, Validators.required],
      lastName: [null, Validators.required]
    });
  }


  addChild(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      firstName: [null, Validators.required],
      lastName: [null, Validators.required]
    });
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the edited stackblitz :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/iterated-according-to-selected-number-dkrxeh?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: You got it. Thanks a lot bro

Comment: @Joseph you'r welome bro

Comment: Is it ok with you, bro?

Comment: @Joseph . Hi i am climbing mountains atm :) . I will go home tomorrow and will post the answer .

Comment: @Joseph . Hi there is already an answe to your question . Does it solve your issue ?

Comment: Yes but he lack something. My friend just commented on his answer.

Comment: @Joseph if he couldnt solve your issue i will try to solve it

Comment: Oh yeah you can! You can make clear and lesser code. Thank you sir

Comment: He replied already and he cant solve it. Maybe you can help. Thank you bro

Comment: @Joseph ok bro . i will post my answer in 2-3 hours

Comment: @Joseph i posted the answer . see if it targets your issue

Comment: Hello brother. My friend just commented on your answer. Thanks brother